# How to construct a compact totally disconnected subset of the unit interval with specific measure

Tags: measure-theory

How to construct a compact totally disconnected subset $E \subset [0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure $m(E) = \epsilon$ for any given $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, without removing any intervals. This question is from Rudin Real and Complex Analyis Chapter 2 Execise 7, but I have added the "without removing any intervals" as the solution to Execise 8 seems to require compact totally disconnected sets with positive measure that are constructed without removing any subsets I believe. I can see how a construction of such sets without the restriction of non-removal of intervals is possible, similar to the Cantor set construction.

Comment: I don't understand.  If it contains an interval, it's not totally disconnected, so how can you do this without removing any intervals?

Comment: What you ask is impossible. Any closed $E\subset [0,1]$ can be constructed by removing intervals. This is because the complement of $E$ is open, and any open set is a countable union of intervals.

Comment: Exercises 7 and 8 are both based on construction of Cantor set and removing intervals is the right way to answer those questions.

Comment: This is my confusion: Exercise 8 is to construct a Borel set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $0 \lt m(E \cap I) \lt m(I)$ for all non-empty open intervals $I$ However for the first inequality to hold $E \cap I \neq \emptyset$ for each $I$ And for the second inequality to hold $E$ must be totally disconnected. Thus my thinking that we need to construct a set of positive measure that is totally disconnected that also shares points with any interval. That such sets exist is shown by the irrationals. However the irrationals fail on the middle inequality. Thus my original question.

Comment: @saulspatz the definition of totally disconnected is that it has no connected subset. So it is true that if The set contains an interval it is not totally disconnected.

Comment: @BiplabDas I don't think you understood me; you're just repeating what I said.

Comment: Yeah it is impossible without removing intervals because complement of that set is open which we know disjoint union of open intervals so we have to remove intervals to get it.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\mathbb{Q} \cap I$ is a countable subset of $I=[0,1]$. Write  $\mathbb{Q}\cap (0,1)=\{r_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Now for $0<\epsilon<1$  consider the set $A=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(r_n- \frac{\epsilon}{2^{(n+1)}},r_n+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{(n+1)}})$. $A$ is an open dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ having measure $\epsilon$. If I assume $A\subset I$ then $I-A$ will work as your set just you have to replace $1-\epsilon$ with $\epsilon$.

But getting $A\subset I$ is a tough task we have to rearrange $r_n$'s value.

Consider $J_1=\{ n\in \mathbb{N}: r_n- \frac{\epsilon}{2^{(n+1)}}<0\}$.
$J_1$ is a subsequence say $\{{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$
[image: .]
For each $r_{n_k}$ we want to find a suitable member say $r_{n_k}'$ to replace with it. Let's see on the interval $ (\frac{\epsilon}{2^{(n+1)}},1-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{(n+1)}})$ because it is safe for $r_{n_k}$, any choice from this interval will not make any trouble for $r_{n_k}$. Now since $ (\frac{\epsilon}{2^{(n+1)}},1-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{(n+1)}})$ has infinitely many rational numbers I will take a rational $r_m$ with a very large index m such that $\frac{\epsilon}{2^{m}}<r_{n_k}$. So now if I replaced them then $|r_n'-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{m}}|=|r_n-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{m}}|>0$. Now whatever $J_1$ is finite or infinite we can do this process which will short out our problem. And we will get a subset $A\subset I$ which is open dense having measure $\epsilon$. Take the complement of it.

**There may be overlapping of the intervals so length will be less than $\epsilon$** I am planning to edit this.

Comment: I think there is some mistake here.